# retry logic uptil databases comes up

Tags: java, database, connection-pooling

Through my java code i m connecting to multiple databases using connection pooling.if my database goes down i need handle the retry logic to get connection until its return a connection object.

Comment: you need to provide a lot more data. What technologies are you using? Database access through JDBC or an ORM like JPA, Hibernate,  JDO etc?
What connection pool lib are you using? Are you using spring? etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your db connection throws some sort of an Exception then you can just sleep for a bit and retry the operation again.

In the example below worker is an object that does some work such as connecting to a db, etc. It's pretty generic so you can retry any sort of an operation such as reading from a file, etc.

Note that catching `Throwable` might not necessarily be a great idea.

```
    boolean success = false;
    int i = 0;
    long delay = retryDelay;

    LOGGER.info("Starting operation");

    /*
     * Loop until you cannot retry anymore or the operation completed successfully
     * The catch block has a nested try catch to ensure that nothing goes wrong
     * while trying to sleep
     * 
     * In case of failure the last retry exception is propagated up to the calling
     * class.
     */
    while (i++ < retryMax && !success)
    {
        try
        {
            worker.work();
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            try
            {
                LOGGER.warn("Caught throwable", t);

                if (i == retryMax) 
                {
                    LOGGER.warn("Retry maximum reached, propagating error");
                    throw t;
                }

                if (retryPolicy == RetryPolicy.ESCALATING) 
                {
                    delay *= 2;
                }

                LOGGER.info("Sleeping for " + delay + " milliseconds");

                Thread.sleep(delay);
            }
            catch (Throwable tt)
            {
                /*
                 * Quick check to see if the maximum has been hit, so we don't log twice
                 * 
                 * t is the original error, and tt is the error we got while retrying
                 * tt would most likely be a InterruptedException or something
                 */
                if (i == retryMax) 
                {
                    throw t;
                }

                LOGGER.warn("Error while retrying, propagating original error up", tt);

                throw t;
            }
        }

    } // end retry loop
```